# size attribute ignored in layer-list

Tags: android, attributes, size, shapes

In the code below, the shape takes up the entire height and width of the layer-list, which means it is ignoring the size attribute.  (It does however listen to the top, left, and right attributes).  I also tried putting height as an attribute of the item rather than the shape, which had no effect.

```
<layer-list >    

    <item ..... />

    <item   
        android:top="2dp"
        android:left="7dp"
        android:right="7dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <size android:height="12dp" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ddffffff"
                android:endColor="#00ffffff"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? I'm not sure why that attribute would exist only to be ignored, but I'll bet if you share your intended results some of us can suggest an alternative drawable/layout/etc.

Comment: Its been a while, I'm having trouble remembering the context.  I'll update it when it comes to me.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using an image view to set this drawable as source, then consider using centerInside

```
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/sample_layer_list" android:scaleType="centerInside" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Other than this option, rest of the option either fit it to entire canvas or trim the shape.

Other option could be to change the size of your imageView itself.

One thing I noticed is that, whatever the size of biggest drawable in your layer list, all shapes inside layer lists are getting scaled to that

Hope it helps.